# Elizabeth's six destinations

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, story, geography

> The ship departed from the Lisbon harbour. Elizabeth sat in her cabin, holding a small USB device in her hand. The important information it contained was meant for the authorities of six foreign powers, and her journey would take her to those countries' capital cities to deliver the data in person.
>
> The carrier came in and left her suitcase by the door. "Here's your suitcase, Mrs. Harcourt", he said.
>
> Elizabeth stared out of her cabin window on the left-hand side of the ship and silently took another sip from her wine glass.

Where was Elizabeth headed?

Comment: *"...and silently took another sip from her wine glass."* $(+1)$ $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: Whoa that’s a good riddle +1

Comment: This is driving me crazy

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think this important mission would take Elizabeth to the six capital cities:

> Port Louis - Mauritius
>  Port Moresby - Papua New Guinea
>  Port Vila - Vanuatu
>  Port-au-Prince - Haiti
>  Port of Spain - Trinidad and Tobago
>  Porto-Novo - Benin

As the report is full of:

> PORTS:  Port Elizabeth - SA, Lisbon - Portugal, harbour - port,  im*port*ant,  USB - Port, this data - a report, carrier - porter, deliver- transport, suitcase - portmanteau, left side of ship - port, wine - port

Comment: Lol, to be honest I had no idea you could use that word for a suitcase. Even better!

Comment: It was a guesstimate - your story was edutaining! Maybe this answer is a [Bass reflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass_reflex)

Comment: Bass reflexes are important to [floor Toms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_tom), the sound is a bit too low to reproduce on regular speakers. (Sorry, no port puns here).

Comment: Was there a significance to the surname Harcourt? I couldn't find one mentioned in the answer but would be surprised if not.

Comment: Thanks are due to M Oehm's supporting [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70520/elizabeths-six-destinations/70525?noredirect=1#comment211056_70523) for Harcourt.

Answer (score 10):

She was going to visit

> Mauritius, Papua New Guinea, Vanuatu, Haiti, Trinidad and Tobago, and Benin.

Explanation:

These things all make an appearance in the story (I may have missed some):

> **Port**ugal (Lisbon)
>  **Port** (harbour)
>  USB **port**
>  im**port**ant information
>  **port**er (the person carrying the luggage)
>  **port**manteau (the luggage)
>  **port**hole (cabin window)
>  **port** (left side of ship)
>  **port** (wine)

And the [capitals of the mentioned countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals)

> all have the word "Port" in them.

Comment: (Hmmm. The book seems a bit of a stretch. I guess you found it because you included the publisher's name in your websearch. Perhaps you were looking for [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_Harcourt)?)

Comment: @M Oehm possibly :-)